# Adding exponents with a multiplying step

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$7^k+7^k * 6$

I understand how to add same base exponents problems.But this problem has a extra part with the *6
I know how and why $7^k+7^k=2*7^k$

But

$7^k+7^k * 6= 7^{1+k}$ Because $7*7^k$

I don't understand why.What happens to the 6 for it to become 7 and what happens to the $7^k$? What are the missing steps that I failing to see?

Comment: Hint:  $1+6 = 7$.

Answer (score 1):

$7^k+6*7^k=1*7^k+6*7^k=(1+6)*7^k=7*7^k=7^{k+1}$

Answer (score 1):

$$7^{k} + (7^k)(6) = (1)(7^k) + (6)(7^k) = (7)(7^k) = 7^{k+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we have the expression of the form a + ab, we can always take out the common term, i.e., 'a' in this case and the resultant expression becomes a.(1+b). Similarly in the given expression 7$^k$+7$^k$.6,we have 7$^k$ as the common term and taking this out we get 7$^k$(1+1.6)= 7.7$^k$